# Chrome data compression and file upload

Tags: android, ajax, google-chrome, video

I've just run into an issue where I am accepting file uploads on a site, I tested this using an android phone running chrome and there was an issue when chrome's bandwidth management was turned on. It ( almost immediately on submission ) returns a Bad Gateway 502 error.

Has anyone come across the same problem...have a solution?

Thanks,
Helen

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Chrome data compression proxy.

Can you provide some more details on exactly what you're trying to do? If you can provide an example URL I can try it out and get some debugging info.

The proxy has some limitations in terms of the size of file uploads which might be biting you.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response. The app is still in dev so releasing the URL isn't possible just yet. But file size will definitely be an issue as we are accepting video files so it could be anything upwards of 100MB. Is there a way to detect and bypass when a user has turned data compression on? Am I right in thinking if this was all behind a https url that chrome data doesn't kick in?

Comment: And just for further information, it's a simple form using javascript to send form data, which includes the video file, to a php backend.

Comment: @mdwelsh We're hitting a similar issue over at apkmirror.com for clients that upload using the Chrome proxy. Here's what happens: http://i.imgur.com/4BrT4M8.png. Any idea how to get this fixed? The size of the upload can be up to 100MB. We'd like to turn Chrome's proxy off for specific upload requests.